# Using a type with generic arguments as constructor in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

Consider the following Typescript code:

```
type CtorType<T> = {
  new(...args: any[]): T;
}

type IWrapper<T> = {
  value: T;
}

function foo<T>(ctor: CtorType<T>): IWrapper<T> {
  return {
    value: new ctor('foo')
  };
}

class A { }
class B<T> { }

const a = foo(A);
const b = foo(B<number>);
```

Strangely, TS compiler throws an error on the last line:

```
TS2348: Value of type 'typeof B<number>' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?
```

Looking at the playground I also see that TS compiles `foo(A)` to just `foo(A)`, but `foo(B<number>)` to `foo(B())`, which is even more surprising.

Why does this happen? Is there a workaround to make it use `B` and maintain the type argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm altering your example code to stop weird issues like the types `A`, `B<string>` and `B<number>` all being the same and not to call the constructors `A` or `B` with a `"foo"` argument they don't accept.

Even in example code, it's a bad idea to have [empty classes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely) or [unused type parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--), as they often lead to unexpected results.

And since your `CTorType<T>` uses the `(...args: any[])` parameter list, it forgets any constraints on the constructor parameters and allows unsafe calls.  The implementation of `foo()` as you have it ends up calling the `A` and `B` constructors with `"foo"` as a parameter, when neither constructor accepts parameters.  So instead I'll use an empty parameter list `()` and only call `new ctor()` inside of `foo()`.

Like this:

```
// zero arg constructor to prevent unsafe calls
type CtorType<T> = {
  new (): T; 
};

type IWrapper<T> = {
  value: T;
};

function foo<T>(ctor: CtorType<T>): IWrapper<T> {
  return {
    value: new ctor() // zero arg call
  };
}

// make A not empty
class A {
  a = "a";
}
// make B not empty and depend on T
class B<T> {
  b: T | undefined = undefined;
}
```

This is just to get the example code to a place where the only issue going on is the question you're trying to solve.

---

Okay, moving on:

`B<number>` is a syntactical error; the compiler is interpreting that as the first part of a generic function call with a specified type argument, such as in `B<number>(13)` assuming `B` was something like `function B<T>(x: T){}`.  But `B` isn't a callable function, it's a constructor, so you get that error.  If it were callable, you'd then get the error that you're missing the call (i.e., `"(" expected`).  There is a *type* named `B<number>`, but no *value* named `B<number>` (in TypeScript, [values are not generic](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574)).

There isn't a short syntax to specify a generic parameter in a function or constructor without calling or `new`ing it.  One thing you can do is to *widen* the constructor from a generic (which can act on all values of the type parameter) to a concrete one (which can only act on a single value of the type parameter), like this:

```
const BNumber: new () => B<number> = B;
const b = foo(BNumber); // IWrapper<B<number>>
```

The first `BNumber` assignment works because `B` is in fact a `new () => B<number>` (as well as a `new () => B<string>` and a `new () => B<Array<{a: string}>>`, etc etc).  Then when you call `foo` on `BNumber`, it returns an `IWrapper<B<number>>` as you desire.

If this is the kind of thing you're going to do with `B` often, you could make the widening into a function that you call, like this:

```
const BWidener = <T>(): new () => B<T> => B;
const bAlso = foo(BWidener<number>()); // IWrapper<B<number>>
const bString = foo(BWidener<string>()); // IWrapper<B<string>>
const bWhatever = foo(BWidener<Array<{ a: string }>>()); // IWrapper<B<{a: string;}[]>>
```

Or, if this is something you're only going to do once and don't mind using [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) then you can do it in one line like this:

```
const bAsWell = foo(B as new () => B<number>); // IWrapper<B<number>>
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/PTAEC8FMCcHtQIbQOagMawHYGcAu0BXNXWaUE0AB2kgDdJNdQCcEAzSdBAG2+wFgAULgCelTgGES0ACpjIAHhkA+UAF5QAbyGhQmSAHdQACgCUALlAyA3EIC+twUNHjQASQDq0BJXHQlqhragrq0PASQljb2jkJsLMQAlligbLCwAcbEpJZSpHLiARbuXj5+AVo6oDS4BNCYlSG6oGHcEZb6RtnQZqAgEDDwSKhoPNxVDvZCQv0AtggA1pwAgnqwTJCzlKJCaNwI2Nigq8G6COqgAEQIl452M2DzS6AAQmsbW6KImAAmoD+QcS-UApGS7faHV4VU6gABGUVAAB9mL9IGxEvo-hoWAD0Zi7tNBBgcExzho0rBjMtTI5iXhXgA5AizWEwDqGEymdSqF4KTDM1nQQKvWlYemwi4U4wvJksmA0vpgTzeXwwBS8-lyoXKISwgB0rQieolGgAjAAGayKkELBAiQl0pgvDyJAH6MgaTLFTqc7lQlR+l6iklw5Z8eDk9LSl1utWawXKMwK-rKspqjUCmDKHVEsVMWEAZXwGNQkcpztdDDVeGgJcTpmTStKqv8vJrdZzjrhHgAFghcHQYJKoxXY-5ltBvCIFJpEJZ25hUHZs0mrSnm+VeZoEPPi4vrHYANoAXWzDrzoewHkgvGH5cQRx9vTUPL5maFjZKKs3b61Z8EQA)